# SQL Query repeats same results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I cannot figure out how to remove the duplicate results from my query in SQL Server. I've tried changing the `ProductID` to one from a different table but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.ProductID,P.ProductDesc,ComponentID,ComponentQty,UnitPrice
FROM  Product P, Manufactured M, ProductSupplier PS
WHERE P.ProductID=PS.ProductID
AND P.ProductID=M.ProductID
AND upper(P.ProductDesc) LIKE upper('Hack Saw%')
OR upper(P.ProductDesc) LIKE upper('saw blade%')
OR upper(P.ProductDesc) LIKE upper('saw handle%')
ORDER BY M.ProductID ASC
```

Output produced is:

```
ProductID  ProductDesc  ComponentID  ComponentQty  UnitPrice
---------  -----------  -----------  ------------  ---------
3          Hack Saw     26           1             27.0000
3          Hack Saw     27           1             27.0000
3          Saw Blade    26           1             2.2500
3          Saw Blade    27           1             2.2500
3          Saw Handle   26           1             3.1700
3          Saw Handle   27           1             3.1700
11         Saw Blade    12           1             2.2500
11         Saw Blade    31           1             2.2500
11         Saw Handle   12           1             3.1700
11         Saw Handle   31           1             3.1700
22         Saw Blade    5            1             2.2500
22         Saw Blade    20           1             2.2500  
22         Saw Blade    21           1             2.2500
22         Saw Handle   5            1             3.1700
22         Saw Handle   20           1             3.1700
22         Saw Handle   21           1             3.1700
```

Comment: You do not really have duplicates. What duplicates do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

There are no duplicate records in your results, the ComponentID values make the rows different.  Removing ComponentID from the result set will make the rows *appear* more similar, and DISTINCT should remove the *apparent* duplicates.  But you probably have a more fundamental problem, either you have multiple entries for the different components, or you are JOINing an extra table into your results.

Comment: Yeah, I think I somehow joined an extra table into my results. Only ProductID 3 should make the saw, ProductIDs 11 and 22 create something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can get distinct rows with a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) in SQL 2008: You can update the `PARTITION BY` to only include columns you wish to be used when considering unique records.

```
WITH WithRowNumber AS
(
   SELECT M.ProductID,P.ProductDesc,ComponentID,ComponentQty,UnitPrice
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.ProductID, P.ProductDesc, ComponentID
         , ComponentQty, UnitPrice ORDER BY M.ProductID ASC) AS RowNumber
   FROM Product AS P
   INNER JOIN Manufactured AS M ON P.ProductID = M.ProductID
   INNER JOIN ProductSupplier AS PS ON P.PruductId = PS.ProductID
   WHERE UPPER(P.ProductDesc) LIKE UPPER('Hack Saw%')
      OR UPPER(P.ProductDesc) LIKE UPPER('saw blade%')
      OR UPPER(P.ProductDesc) LIKE UPPER('saw handle%')
)
SELECT wrn.ProductID, wrn.ProductDesc, wrn.ComponentID, wrn.ComponentQty
   , wrn.UnitPrice
FROM WithRowNumber AS wrn
WHERE wrn.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: @marc_s I have a hard time reading anything other than explicit `JOIN` syntax, which ends up working out in my favor :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *ComponentID* from the SELECT and it will eliminate the apparent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

are your CompoentID stored in ProductSupplier table ? it might be you have duplicate entries in ProductSupplier table since you have different ComponentID but same qty/unit price.

You have to clarify more if this is actually a common business scenario in your application or it might be identify from effective date.